# Nightwatch.js: Drag and Drop

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop, nightwatch.js

I am trying to test a drag and drop operation using Nightwatch.js 0.8.18, Selenium Server 2.53.0 and Chrome Driver 2.21.2.

Basically, I take the approach described at https://github.com/RobK/nightwatchjs-drag-n-drop-example/blob/master/spec/drag-and-drop.js – i.e.: something like ...

```
.moveToElement('some-xpath-expression', 10, 10)
.pause(100)
.mouseButtonDown(0)
.pause(100)
.moveToElement('other-xpath-expression', 30, 30)
.pause(100)
.mouseButtonUp(0)
```

The cursor moves to the element to be dragged (perceivable by the `:hover` style of the icon the mouse is over), but then nothing happens. It looks to me like the `mouseButtonDown()` action has no effect. (But who knows for sure?)

It makes no difference if I use Firefox instead of Chrome – the behavior is exactly the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: which operating system you are using? Can you share html? Code you wrote working fine for me on Windows but failing on OSX.

Comment: Interesting point – I’m using OS X, and have so far not bothered with trying it on Windows. Will try to verify this in the next days.

Comment: It's not working for me on Windows either. The `mouseButtonDown()` doesn't trigger the HTML5 drag&drop API.

Answer (score 3):

Guys you have to try this and it works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Just you have to install "html-dnd" using npm, as well as this is a link:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd

After installing you just have to execute this command

`browser.execute(dragAndDrop, ['#draggable', '#droppable']);`

For Example:

```
var dragAndDrop = require('html-dnd').codeForSelectors;
browser.execute(dragAndDrop,['#elemendId1','#elemendId2']).pause(2000);
```

Hope this will work fine for your test cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me (Selenium 3, ChromeDriver) – the command does not seem to do anything. Nevertheless, thanks for answering.

Comment: This worked for me, but the require is wrong per the docs.  Should be `var dragAndDrop = require("html-dnd").codeForSelects`. See docs for using with nightwatch.

Comment: This works for me using nightwatch-js on BrowserStack

Comment: Has anyone been able to use `html-dnd` with an xpath selector instead of css. I have been getting `invalid element state: Failed to execute "querySelector" on "Document"`. I can confirm that the xpath expression I am using is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The moment you click the element the expression changes and thus the tests 'forgets' what they were supposed to be clicking.

It's recommended to use an action build approach as so:

http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop

Answer (score 0):

Currently at `Nightwatch` Version 1.5.1 I'm able to drag and drop with the following example.

**Example:**

```js
"Step 1: Drag and Drop": function (browser) {
    browser.moveToElement('yourLocator', '#startingElement', 0, 0);
    browser.mouseButtonDown(0);
    browser.moveToElement('yourLocator', '#endingElement', 0, 0);
    browser.mouseButtonUp(0);
}
```